# Connecting to mysql on localhost using external hostname

Tags: mysql, localhost

I'm trying to connect to my server using the external IP Address...
This works from an external machine but not from the machine which is running mysql.

This is annoying as I would like to use the same config file on the mysql server as other servers.

Is there a way to connect to mysql using either localhost or the external IP on the mysql host machine?

Thxs.

Comment: Are you trying to connect to the mysql server, from other servers with the same settings on each different server? Its hard to know what exactly you are trying to do.

Comment: What exactly is happening?  You cannot establish a TCP connection to mysql server or you cannot login when coming from local server?